# Game Theory: MEX rule and Nimbers

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, numbers, game-theory

I've been reading this small [tutorial](https://www.mathcamp.org/gettoknowmathcamp/academics/archives/Alfonso-CGT-lectures.pdf) on Nimbers and game theory.

Could someone explain *why* the mex rule governs the nimber of a game position?

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)

From the minimal excluded ordinal, it seems to me that the Nimber for a state is actually the minimum state that the person 'cannot' reach. How does that help in governing the state of the current game ?

I see a proof on Wikipedia, but I don't understand anything from it. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem#Proof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire idea of a nimber is to draw an analogy with the well understood game of Nim.  So unless you understand THAT game, it won't make sense to you.

In the game of Nim we have a set of piles of things.  On each turn, you take as many things as you want from one pile and one pile only.  The winner is the person to take the last thing from the last pile.

Now try to convince yourself of the following facts.

1. In Nim, the nimber of a single pile is the size of that pile.
2. If we have a 2 pile game, the nimber of the position is the xor of the sizes of the two piles.  (You will need to do a double induction.)
3. If we take the set of piles and split it into two, then the nimber of the whole position is the xor of the nimbers of the two subsets.

Now here is the point.  Replace the piles with arbitrary deterministic games with a guaranteed win/lose.  Turn the collection into a game where you're taking turns with different games, and the person who wins the last game wins.  The nimber as defined above tells you, by analogy with Nim, how to play the combined game perfectly.

If you're playing just the regular 2 person game, then the only fact about the nimber that you actually need to know is whether it is 0 (you're in a losing position) or non-zero (you're in a winning position).  The exact nimber is only useful when you can break a complex game into a collection of separate games that you are choosing between on each turn.  However a surprising number of mathematical games do admit of such a structure.

Comment: I kinda do understand that bit.. What I don't understand is why the nimber of a position is the minimal excluded nimber on the set of possible moves? Is it because if we have a possible move to a 0 nimber then the mex will be non zero and hence winning??

Comment: The minimal excluded nimber is the first thing that your opponent could do to you that you can't respond to by playing in that game.

Comment: The mex nimber is not in 'my' set of possible moves. How is it ensured that the opponent can always reach that nimber ?

Comment: That is not ensured.  Some positions you can win from. :-)

The point is that you come up with the right strategy for the combined game by looking at the xors of the nimbers of the individual games.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was like this:

1. Understand Nim, and why the strategy works
2. Understand Poker Nim, and why the strategy is the same
3. Understand why the mex is the important number

Poker Nim is just like Nim, except that the players hold onto the ``coins'' that they remove, and on their turn, they may either move any positive number of coins from one stack into their hand, or move any positive number of coins from their hand onto one stack.

Initially, this feels very different. Play can even proceed for infinitely many moves! But that doesn't happen if Bob and Alice are playing hard. Suppose Bob looks at the stacks and sees that he would have a winning strategy if they were playing Nim and not Poker Nim. He can adapt that strategy to Nim as follows: if Alice takes coins off the table, he proceeds as if he is playing Nim; if Alice puts coins onto the table, he immediately removes the coins she just placed. Since she can only have finitely many coins in her hand, she can only stall finitely many times before she is forced to make her losing Nim move.

In Poker Nim, if I have 5 coins in hand and I look at a stack of 3 coins, I can on my move change it to any have 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8 coins. What I can't do is leave it at the mex, which is 3. If I move it down, I am playing Nim. I move it up, you can immediately reverse it back to 3, and I am facing the same situation I was except that now I have fewer than 5 coins in hand.

So that's Poker Nim, and the essence of how the mex becomes relevant. Moves above the mex are reversible, and so cannot ever turn a losing position into a winning won. Moving above the mex is never helpful. Unless you are trying to overwhelm the computational power of your opponent, that is.